# Leaflet Marker not showing with draggable as true

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

With my custom Draggable Marker below, if I set the draggable property as true, the marker stop being displayed in map. Does any of u know how to solve this?

```
 const DraggableMarker = () => {
    const markerRef = useRef(null);
    const eventHandlers = useMemo(
      () => ({
        dragend() {
          const marker: any = markerRef.current;
          if (marker != null) {
            console.log(marker.getLatLng())
            setCurrentCoords(marker.getLatLng());
          }
        },
      }),
      [],
    );

    return (
      <Marker
      position={[currentCoords.lat ?? 0, currentCoords.lng ?? 0]}
      icon={customMarkerIcon()}
      eventHandlers={eventHandlers}
      ref={markerRef}
      draggable={false}
      interactive={true}
      ></Marker>
    );
  };

// Custom icon:
 const customMarkerIcon = () => {
    const color = '#cb2a29';
    let svgTemplate = null;

    svgTemplate = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" className="marker" opacity="0.7"  >
    <path fill-opacity=".35" d="M16 32s1.427-9.585 3.761-12.025c4.595-4.805 8.685-.99 8.685-.99s4.044 
    3.964-.526 8.743C25.514 30.245 16 32 16 32z"/>
    <path fill="#${color}" stroke="#fff" d="M15.938 32S6 17.938 6 11.938C6 .125 15.938 0 15.938 0S26 
    .125 26 11.875C26 18.062 15.938 32 15.938 32zM16 6a4 4 0 100 8 4 4 0 000-8z"/>
  </svg>`;

    const customIcon = L.divIcon({
      className: 'custom-icon',
      html: svgTemplate,
      iconSize: [32, 32],
    });

    return customIcon;
  };
```

I even tried using the default marker, but got the same exactly bug.